# Cannot Intent to another activity

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I was added `buttonNext` then I set `onClickListener`. When the button is clicked and the barcode is the same as in firestore then the Intent to ViewData class, and the problem is when the button is clicked and the barcode is not the same as in firestore, it cannot be intent to `AddItems` class.

**Code :**

```
    collectionReference.whereEqualTo("barCode", scanResult).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("barCode") != null) { // Success intent to ViewData
                        collectionReference.document(queryDocumentSnapshot.getId()).update("productQuantity", FieldValue.increment(1));
                        Intent moveView = new Intent(ScannersActivity.this, ViewData.class);
                        moveView.putExtra("documentID", documentID);
                        startActivity(moveView);
                        finish();
                    } else { // Problem here..
                        Intent moveCode = new Intent(ScannersActivity.this, AddItems.class);
                        moveCode.putExtra("sendDocumentID", documentID);
                        moveCode.putExtra("ScanResult", scanResult);
                        startActivity(moveCode);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: when bar code not same as firestore else part execute or not?

Comment: yap, when barcode is not available in firestore then else part is executed @RajGohel

Comment: Okay, then AddItems activity not opening or data not getting in that activity?

Comment: AddItems activity not opening when i click buttonNext @RajGohel

Comment: If you add a log statement in your else part is something printed out in the logcat? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Please verify you not forgot to declare activity in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

var isBarCodeAvailable = false

```
    for (queryDocumentSnapshot in task.getResult()) {
        if (queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("barCode") != null) {
            isBarCodeAvailable = true
            break
        } else {
            isBarCodeAvailable = false
            break
        }
    }

    if (isBarCodeAvailable) {
        collectionReference.document(queryDocumentSnapshot.getId())
            .update("productQuantity", FieldValue.increment(1))
        val moveView = Intent(this@ScannersActivity, ViewData::class.java)
        moveView.putExtra("documentID", documentID)
        startActivity(moveView)
        finish()
    } else {
        val moveCode = Intent(this@ScannersActivity, AddItems::class.java)
        moveCode.putExtra("sendDocumentID", documentID)
        moveCode.putExtra("ScanResult", scanResult)
        startActivity(moveCode)
        finish()
    }
```